# transformar numero a fecha

Tags: vba, date

tengo el siguiente numero 34076 que equivale a la fecha 17-04-1993, que función puedo utilizar para transformar ese numero a la fecha indicada, estoy trabajando con VBA y ese numero se recupera desde un excel a un datagridview.

Comment: ¿Y que relación hay entre el número y la fecha?

Comment: las fechas en excel las transforma a numero y cuando importo el excel a un datagrid view me coloca es numero

Comment: Faltó compartir los buscado/investigado sobre el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al final lo que hice fue una funcion para transformar los string y declarar en el excel tipo general la columna

```
Function Conversion(fecha As String)
    Dim sDate As String = fecha
    Dim rDate As String
    Dim Y As Long, M As Long, D As Long


    If Mid(sDate, 3, 1) = 0 And Mid(sDate, 1, 1) = 0 Then
        Y = Mid(sDate, 5, 8)
        M = Mid(sDate, 3, 2)
        D = Mid(sDate, 1, 2)
        rDate = "0" & D & "-0" & M & "-" & Y
    ElseIf Mid(sDate, 1, 1) = 0 Then
        Y = Mid(sDate, 5, 8)
        M = Mid(sDate, 3, 2)
        D = Mid(sDate, 1, 2)
        rDate = "0" & D & "-" & M & "-" & Y

    ElseIf Mid(sDate, 3, 1) = 0 Then
        Y = Mid(sDate, 5, 8)
        M = Mid(sDate, 3, 2)
        D = Mid(sDate, 1, 2)
        rDate = D & "-0" & M & "-" & Y
    ElseIf Mid(sDate, 3, 1) <> 0 And Mid(sDate, 1, 1) <> 0 Then
        Y = Mid(sDate, 5, 8)
        M = Mid(sDate, 3, 2)
        D = Mid(sDate, 1, 2)
        rDate = D & "-" & M & "-" & Y
    End If
    Return rDate
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que convertir desde OLE Automation:

```
DateTime MyFecha = DateTime.FromOADate(ValorFechaExcel);
```